# Cap deploy error on ubuntu with rails 3.1.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, ubuntu, capistrano

Here is the deploy error:

```
servers: ["176.195.225.93"]
Password:
    [176.195.225.93] executing command
 ** [176.195.225.93 :: err] fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
 ** [176.195.225.93 :: err] fatal: early EOF
 ** [176.195.225.93 :: err] fatal: index-pack failed
```

Here is the first half of deploy.rb:

```
require "bundler/capistrano"
set :application, "byop"
set :repository,  "git://github.com/mclab/byop.git"
set :scm, :git
set :user, "username"
set :use_sudo, true
set :scm_passphrase, "string"
set :branch, "master"
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/#{application}"
set :keep_releases, 3
ssh_options[:paranoid] = false
ssh_options[:port] = 22
set :default_environment, {
  'PATH' => "/home/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin:/home/admin/.rvm/bin:/home/admin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin:$PATH",
  'RUBY_VERSION' => 'ruby 1.9.3',
  'GEM_HOME'     => '/home/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125',
  'GEM_PATH'     => '/home/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems',
  'BUNDLE_PATH'  => '/home/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin'  # If you are using bundler.
}   

server "176.195.225.93", :web, :app, :db, :primary => true
```

It seems that the server side hung up. What could cause the error? Thanks so much.

Comment: Is this the complete output you get? Usually cap prints the actual comand before executing it on the server. That's missing.